# Perl script for checking network

Tags: mysql, perl, unix

I am new to Perl and for practice I am writing a simple perl script to check my home network for available ip addresses and check their mac address , vendor and opened ports for each of them.
All that information i want to put in mysql db.
Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::Ping;
use Net::ARP;
use DBI;
use IO::Socket::PortState qw(check_ports);
require config;
my $proto   = 'tcp';
my @ports    = (21,22,23,80,8080);
my $address;
my $ping_timeout = 1;
my $host;
for my $i (18..21)
{
        $host = "10.20.1.$i";
        my $timeout = 1;
        my $pinger  = Net::Ping->new('icmp', $timeout);
        print "$host  ";
        if ($pinger->ping($host))
        {
                my $mac = Net::ARP::arp_lookup("em0","$host");
                my $vendor = vendor_lookup($mac);
                $vendor=~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
                print "$mac  $vendor  ";
                foreach my $port (@ports)
                {
                        my($section, $ping_timeout, %porthash);
                        $porthash{$proto}{$port}{'name'} = $section;
                        check_ports($host, $ping_timeout, \%porthash);
                        my $open = $porthash{$proto}{$port}{'open'};
                        if ($open) {
                                print "$port ";
                        }
                }
                print "\n";
        }
}
```

If i run the script i will receive something like that:

```
10.20.1.18  38:ea:a7:6f:d9:05  Hewlett Packard  80 8080 
10.20.1.19  fc:15:b4:31:77:76  Hewlett Packard  80 8080 
10.20.1.20  e8:39:35:25:dd:36  Hewlett Packard  22 80
```

My problem is that i don't seem to find an answer how to combine all that information ($host,$mac,$vendor,$port) and put it in the database cause if we put the $port variable in @array it will have a different size from the other arrays.

My database structure is looking like that:

```
+----+------------+-------------------+--------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| id | ip         | mac               | opened_ports | vendor          | date                |
+----+------------+-------------------+--------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 10.20.1.19 | fc:15:b4:31:77:76 | NULL         | Hewlett Packard | 2016-02-15 15:50:19 |
|  2 | 10.20.1.20 | e8:39:35:25:dd:36 | NULL         | Hewlett Packard | 2016-02-15 15:50:19 |
|  3 | 10.20.1.21 | 8c:dc:d4:5d:21:7b | NULL         | Hewlett Packard | 2016-02-15 15:50:19 |
|  4 | 10.20.1.18 | 38:ea:a7:6f:d9:05 | NULL         | Hewlett Packard | 2016-02-15 16:02:09 |
|  5 | 10.20.1.19 | fc:15:b4:31:77:76 | NULL         | Hewlett Packard | 2016-02-15 16:02:09 |
|  6 | 10.20.1.20 | e8:39:35:25:dd:36 | NULL         | Hewlett Packard | 2016-02-15 16:02:10 |
|  7 | 10.20.1.21 | 8c:dc:d4:5d:21:7b | NULL         | Hewlett Packard | 2016-02-15 16:02:10 |
+----+------------+-------------------+--------------+-----------------+---------------------+
```

This is imported information without the information for the opened ports.

Comment: Have you decided on a database layout yet? Please [edit] your question and share that as well. It looks to me like what you need is to normalize your DB.

Comment: I have shared the db structure.

Comment: What data type is `opened_ports`?

Comment: Change that, then. What is the real problem here?

Comment: With a single column for multiple port numbers, your database will not be in [1NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). If you want it to be, create a second table with columns (`id`, `port`). Every entry in the `port` column will be a single port number.

Comment: @reinierpost I got distracted while writing my answer, I didn't want to steal your comment ;)

Comment: Great to see it turned into an answer!

Answer (score 1):

[Your database is not normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). You have a basic 1:N relation where each line can have zero or more `opened_ports`.

The correct way to deal with that is to create a second table and have N rows per `id`. It would look something like this:

```
+-------+--------------+
| id_fk | opened_ports |
+-------+--------------+
|  1    | 22           |
|  1    | 80           |
|  3    | 22           |
+-------+--------------+
```

Then you remove the column `opened_ports` fro your main table, and link them through the `id`.

In your Perl program, you need to now do two inserts. The first one will be for the large table, which will also create your (probably auto_increment) `id`. You can fetch that by calling [`$dbh->last_insert_id`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#last_insert_id). After that, you use it to do subsequent second insert statements (or a combined one) on the small table that holds the ports.

Answer (score 0):

Below the initial print statement `print "$mac  $vendor  ";` you know the mac vendor host and date at this point so `prepare` an insert statement with a placeholder `(?)` for the port number

Then at the line to print the port number add an execute statement with the port in the placeholder position

To do the reporting use a schema like this

```
create table scan (
  id int,
  ip char(15),
  mac char(20),
  opened_ports int,
  vendor varchar(255),
  d datetime
  );
```

here is test data based on your examples above

```
INSERT INTO SCAN (Id,IP,MAC,OPENED_PORTS,VENDOR,D) VALUES(1,'10.20.1.19','fc:15:b4:31:77:76',25,'Hewlett Packard','2016-02-15 15:50:19');
INSERT INTO SCAN (Id,IP,MAC,OPENED_PORTS,VENDOR,D) VALUES(2,'10.20.1.20','e8:39:35:25:dd:36',80,'Hewlett Packard','2016-02-15 15:50:19');
INSERT INTO SCAN (Id,IP,MAC,OPENED_PORTS,VENDOR,D) VALUES(3,'10.20.1.21','8c:dc:d4:5d:21:7b',8080,'Hewlett Packard','2016-02-15 15:50:19');
INSERT INTO SCAN (Id,IP,MAC,OPENED_PORTS,VENDOR,D) VALUES(4,'10.20.1.18','38:ea:a7:6f:d9:05',137,'Hewlett Packard','2016-02-15 16:02:09');
INSERT INTO SCAN (Id,IP,MAC,OPENED_PORTS,VENDOR,D) VALUES(5,'10.20.1.19','fc:15:b4:31:77:76',443,'Hewlett Packard','2016-02-15 16:02:09');
INSERT INTO SCAN (Id,IP,MAC,OPENED_PORTS,VENDOR,D) VALUES(6,'10.20.1.20','e8:39:35:25:dd:36',8080,'Hewlett Packard','2016-02-15 16:02:10');
INSERT INTO SCAN (Id,IP,MAC,OPENED_PORTS,VENDOR,D) VALUES(7,'10.20.1.21','8c:dc:d4:5d:21:7b',22,'Hewlett Packard','2016-02-15 16:02:10');
```

and here is a query that makes output as required

```
select ip,mac,GROUP_CONCAT(opened_ports) as port,vendor, d from scan group by ip;
```

Comment: The problem is that there may be any number of port numbers for the same IP address.

Comment: Each row in the database is unique by "id" not by "ip"  so multiple rows with the same ip can be inserted

Comment: Actually you don't know that. OP didn't say that in the question. Might as well have a unique index.

Comment: It is probably true, but this won't produce a normalized database (not in 3NF). The OP must tell whether that is acceptable.

Comment: My answer does fit in with the OP's script and sketchy description of their database.  And that's the magic of SO

Comment: @reinierpost  is right ,the main problem is that there are several number of port numbers for the same IP address. And i do not know how to combine them so i can receive similar output in the db:


 `|10.20.1.19 | fc:15:b4:31:77:76 | 21,80,22 | Hewlett Packard | 2016-02-15 15:50:19 |`

Comment: I have updated the answer with an example schema that works and a query that gives the type of output required